# Any ways to validate Apex script without running it?

Tags: apex, validation

We have a product where user can specify some apex script and we run them as `execute anonymous` apex script.

We want to provide a `validate script` options which checks for syntax and other issues without running it. Is there any api todo that or do that using some other trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no real way to do this without "running" the code, unless you want to write your own parser/compiler and try to validate everything manually. Obviously, that's not a sustainable model.

However, there is a potential trick you could use. Simply add `return;` to the beginning of whatever they give you and call executeAnonymous. The code will either compile successfully and immediately return, or you'll get a compilation error you can report back to the user.